# Animating tooltip fade in and out

Tags: css

how can I make this tooltip show and hide with fade? I have tried to add:

```
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
```

but with no luck, here is my code

Tooltip css:

```
.mainButtonContainer button:hover:after
{

    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-color: #093466;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 2px 2px;
    bottom: -5px;
    color: #093466;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 113px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

html:

```
<button  id=mgf_main1 type="button" onclick="loadData(1)">
    <img src="Images/Magof-Icon.png" width="68" height="68"/>
</button>
```

[jsfiddle.net/rdRhS](http://jsfiddle.net/rdRhS)

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: you need to include the transition in both the hover and default states. Also, the transition code says that opacity will transition, but you also need to set / change the opacity property on hover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move everything that describes the element to `button:after`, and only change the properties that change on hover in `button:hover:after`.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdRhS/2/)

```
button:after {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

    content:'';
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-color: #093466;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 2px 2px;
    bottom: -5px;
    color: #093466;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:70px;
    width: 113px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: -1;
}

button:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;    
}
```